# Alias in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

How can i use alias in laravel? Here's my approach but i'm getting an error of.

**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'Tbl_payroll_employee_basic' doesn't exist** 
   **Query**

```
$data["_leave_info"] = Tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev3::select('*','basicapprover.payroll_employee_display_name','basicreliever.payroll_employee_display_name')
->leftjoin('Tbl_payroll_employee_basic AS basicreliever', 'basicreliever.payroll_employee_id', '=', 'Tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev3.payroll_employee_id_reliever')
    ->leftjoin('Tbl_payroll_employee_basic AS basicapprover', 'basicapprover.payroll_employee_id', '=', 'Tbl_payroll_leave_schedulev3.payroll_employee_id_approver')
    ->get();
```

**Tbl_payroll_leave_schedule_v3** **table**

```
+----+--------------+-------------+--------------------------+
| payroll_employee_id_approver | payroll_employee_id_reliever|
+----+--------------+-------------+--------------------------+
|                              |                             |
|             2                |               3             |
+----+--------------+-------------+--------------------------+
```

**Tbl_payroll_employee_basic** **table**

```
+----+--------------+-------------+--------------------------+
|       payroll_employee_id    | payroll_employee_displayname|
+----+--------------+-------------+--------------------------+
|             2                |     Goku                    |
|             3                |     Naruto                  |
+----+--------------+-------------+--------------------------+
```

**UPDATE**

I found the cause of the problem, the cause is **MISPELLED** the `table` **`Tbl_payroll_employee_basic`** it should be **`tbl_payroll_employee_baisc`**. So be sure to double check the spelling of all your tables.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid i edited, there is no digimahouse there. My bad. Is my syntax correct in using `alias` sir?

Comment: Your query looks fine make sure you have executed all migrations

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Hello sir, i found the cause of the error. `"Tbl_payroll_employee_basic"` should be `"tbl_payroll_employee_basic"`. Thank you for saying that the syntax is correct. So i double check the table names. Should i delete this thread?

Comment: I guess you don't need to delete your post instead you could update your question and add the cause of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel supports aliases on tables and columns with AS. Try doing it with using alias before executing query and store it in a variable and use it in the query. Below is one working example of aliases in laravel.

```
$users = DB::table('some_very_very_long_table_name AS t')
           ->select('t.id AS uid')
           ->get();
```

Hope this helps.